# Query a collection using PropertyInfo object in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have a method with a signature like this

```
void RefreshMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> lst, string propertyName) where T:class
{
   Type type = typeof(T);
   PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperties().Single(u => u.Name == primaryKeyProperty);
  //query goes here
}
```

Now i want to query that collection for getting all the values whose

> propertyName < 0

In a simple scenario it would be as easy as this

```
lst.where(u=>u.ID<0)
```

But here i don't have that ID property but have corresponding "PropertyInfo" object.

How should i acheive this.

kindly guide

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can lookup the property-value using `property.GetValue(anObjectOfTypeT, null)`.

So something like:

```
var refreshedList =  lst.Where(l => ((int)(property.GetValue(l, null)) < 0).ToList();
```

This assumes the property will always be of type int though.

Comment: Brilliant, just what I needed :)

Comment: Is there a way to do it for other types of properties?

Comment: @Scar What do you mean, a property of type string, or double, or some other type? You can change the casting to `int`, but you do need to know the type beforehand.

Comment: @Maarten I mean if i have to do this for multiple properties of different types, is there any other way other than create a different var for each datatype?