# Reflection call a method in a class which is in a list

Tags: c#, list, reflection

I have a class with some setters and getters called Customer which holds some string values. I then create a List and add many of the Customer class to it. How do i then access the getter and setter methods using reflection?

```
List<Customer> Customers; // assume we have filled it
Customers[0].Name; // how do I use reflection to call this from a string?
```

Also the Customer class, Customers and the Name method are all public.

I am in a situation where I need to dynamically get the value from the class based on the column the user is trying to edit. The column name is the name of the method I need to call.

I have looked into the GetType().GetMethod() and my question is how to use it with a list like I have above.

An example would solve my problem.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here...

Comment: Why reflection? So you have `Name` and you want to access the `Name` property, you have `Number` and you want to access the `Number` property. Why do you need this inefficient and error-prone approach?

Comment: PropertyInfo.GetValue http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385.aspx

Comment: *"my question is how to use it with a list like I have above."* A `List<>` is just a container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example should get you started:

```
var namePropertyInfo = typeof(Customer).GetProperty("Name");
var name = namePropertyInfo.GetValue(Customers[0], null);
```

Now, `name` is an instance of `object` with value equal to `Customer[0].Name`. Proceed accordingly.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for I guess I just had the syntax wrong but this is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: There is a nice post which explains how to and provides code for accessing methods or properties with refactor safe code.  http://www.codeducky.org/10-utilities-c-developers-should-know-part-two/

---

All the given answers will work.  However, none are refactor safe.  I thought I'd offer a solution that a bit more refactor safe.

```
//Create a dictionary of columnName => property info using the GetPropertyInfo method.
public static IDictionary<string, PropertyInfo> propertyInfos = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>
    {
        {"Name", GetPropertyInfo((Customer c) => c.Name) }
    };

List<Customer> Customers= new List<Customer> { new Customer { Name = "Peter Pan" } };
Customer customer = Customers[0];
string column = "Name";
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = propertyInfos[column];
//Set property
propertyInfo.SetValue(customer, "Captain Hook", null);
//Get property -- Returns Captain Hook
object propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(customer, null);
```

I've taken `GetPropertyInfo` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression/672212#672212).  I slightly modified it by removing the `source` parameter because you can see by *HappyNomad's* comment that it's not necessary for the newest version of C#.

```
public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<TSource, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> propertyLambda)
{
    Type type = typeof(TSource);

    MemberExpression member = propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (member == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
            "Expression '{0}' refers to a method, not a property.",
            propertyLambda.ToString()));

    PropertyInfo propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (propInfo == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
            "Expression '{0}' refers to a field, not a property.",
            propertyLambda.ToString()));

    if (type != propInfo.ReflectedType &&
        !type.IsSubclassOf(propInfo.ReflectedType))
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
            "Expresion '{0}' refers to a property that is not from type {1}.",
            propertyLambda.ToString(),
            type));

    return propInfo;
}
```

My suggestion is a bit more refactor safe because you'll hit a compile time error every time you change the `Name` property on `Customer`.

Side note: I agree with *Tim S.*.  You'll likely be able to find a safer and more performant way than reflection :).

Answer (score 1):

It depends where the "dynamic" part of your question starts.  Do you need to access the List itself dynamically?  If so, then you have *two* dynamic (reflection) calls to make.  However, if you have access to the List directly, and you can use the indexer to find the right customer, and only *then* do you need to use a reflection call, then your code will look something like:

```
var fieldName = "Name";
var customer = Customers[x];
Type type = typeof(Customer);
var prop = type.GetProperties().Single(field => field.Name == fieldName);

// once you have your propinfo + your reference to the right customer, just call...
Object value = prop.GetValue(customer, null); // you'll need to cast/convert away from object
```

See [Query a collection using PropertyInfo object in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431546/query-a-collection-using-propertyinfo-object-in-linq) for more details

Comment: I don't have any way of knowing the index and column without a great deal of code, I intentional kept my example simple to get the exact answer I wanted although yours works as well and is a good lambada expression example which I am also unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer to just what you're asking:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Customer> Customers= new List<Customer> { new Customer { Name = "John Smith" } };
    GetProp(Customers[0], "Name"); // "John Smith"
    SetProp(Customers[0], "Name", "Joe");
    GetProp(Customers[0], "Name"); // "Joe"
}
object GetProp(Customer customer, string propertyName)
{
    var property = typeof(Customer).GetProperty(propertyName);
    return property.GetValue(customer);
}
void SetProp(Customer customer, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
{
    var property = typeof(Customer).GetProperty(propertyName);
    property.SetValue(customer, propertyValue);
}
```

Or working on a not-strongly-typed list:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Customer> Customers= new List<Customer> { new Customer { Name = "John Smith" } };
    string name = (string)GetProp(Customers, 0, "Name"); // name == "John Smith"
}
object GetProp(object customerList, int index, string propertyName)
{
    var custList = (IList)customerList;
    var customer = custList[index];
    var nameProperty = customer.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    return nameProperty.GetValue(customer);
}
```

And here's what I think you should really do: do not use reflection as part of modifying values in a table/grid, and not based on the column name (display value and property name aren't always the same). What should you do? That depends on what framework you're working with: WPF? ASP.NET web site? WinForms?

Comment: I may consider this code later on and appreciate the comments as well since I have never really used reflection before. I am not using reflection to modify data in any way only to retrieve it in some parts of my modified ListView.