# Linq query - "Where" on List<T> Where reflected property Contains text/value

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I would like to build a Function where user could search if certain property from list contains value

Let say we will have List, and Company will be defined as a class with properties like :

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CompanyAddress1 { get; set; }
    public string CompanyPostCode { get; set; }
    public string CompanyCity { get; set; }
    public string CompanyCounty { get; set; }
}
```

Now - Ideally I would like to have function with this parameters

```
List<Company> FilterCompanies(List<Company> unfilteredList, string fieldToQueryOn, string query)
{
    // linq  version what ideally would like to archeve
    return unfilteredList.Where(x => x."fieldToQueryOn".ToString().ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower())).ToList();
}
```

and call :

```
var variable = FilterCompanies(NotNullFilledUnfilteredList, "CompanyCity", "New York")
```

I tried to follow the tutorial at [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries) and it's easy, but I don't have clue how to extend that solution with reflection on Type and use it in an expression tree.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query a collection using PropertyInfo object in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431546/query-a-collection-using-propertyinfo-object-in-linq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Type.GetProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx) to find a property by name using reflection, and then use [`GetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385.aspx) to retrieve the value:

```
List<Company> FilterCompanies(List<Company> list, string propertyName, string query)
{
    var pi = typeof(Company).GetProperty(propertyName);

    query = query.ToLower();
    return list
        .Where(x => pi.GetValue(x).ToString().ToLower().Contains(query))
        .ToList();
}
```

You should probably add some error handling though in case someone uses a property that is invalid. For example, you could do `(pi?.GetValue(x) ?? string.Empty).ToString().ToLower()…` to be on the safe side.

I’ve also moved the `query.ToLower()` out of the lambda expression to make sure it only runs once. You can also try other case-insensitive ways to check whether `query` is a substring of the value to avoid having to convert any string. Check out the question [“Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring) for more information.

Btw. if you are generally interested in running dynamic queries, you should take a look at [dynamic LINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/).

Comment: good answer, instead of ToLower you could use `OrdinalIgnoreCase`

Comment: Yes [`IndexOf` and Ignore case is going to be more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15464440/542251) than `ToLower`(ing) everything.

Comment: Thanks! I Didn't expect that simple reflection will allow me to accomplish the task. I Marked your answer as accepted because its strict in typecasting and doesn't require extension methods

Answer (score 5):

Generics and lambda:

```
namespace WhereTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var companies = new[] { new Company { Id = 1, Name = "abc" }, new Company { Id = 2, CompanyAddress1 = "abc" } };
            foreach (var company in FilterCompanies(companies, "abc", x => x.Name, x => x.CompanyCity))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(company.Id);
            }
        }

        static List<Company> FilterCompanies(IEnumerable<Company> unfilteredList, string query, params Func<Company, string>[] properties)
        {
            return unfilteredList.Where(x => properties.Any(c => c.Invoke(x) == query)).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class Company
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CompanyAddress1 { get; set; }
        public string CompanyPostCode { get; set; }
        public string CompanyCity { get; set; }
        public string CompanyCounty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Advantages: no reflection, strongly typed code.

Comment: Thanks, I can't use it in this case, but Its good lesson for future ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GetProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty(v=vs.110).aspx) combined with [GetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
List<Company> FilterCompanies(List<Company> unfilteredList, string fieldToQueryOn, string query)
{
   return unfilteredList
       .Where(x => x.GetType.GetProperty(fieldToQueryOn).GetValue(x)
       .ToString().ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower())).ToList();
}
```

OR: [property accessors using string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283206/c-sharp-setting-getting-the-class-properties-by-string-name) (same as javascript `obj[property]`)

You can modify your class:

```
public class Company
{
    // just add this code block to all your classes that would need to access
    // your function
    public object this[string propertyName] 
    {
        get{
            Type myType = typeof(Company);                   
            PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            return myPropInfo.GetValue(this, null);
        }
        set{
            Type myType = typeof(Company);                   
            PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            myPropInfo.SetValue(this, value, null);
        }

    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CompanyAddress1 { get; set; }
    public string CompanyPostCode { get; set; }
    public string CompanyCity { get; set; }
    public string CompanyCounty { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can change your function like this:

```
List<Company> FilterCompanies(List<Company> unfilteredList, string key, string query)
{
    // linq  version what ideally would like to archeve
    return unfilteredList.Where(x => x[key].ToString().ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower())).ToList();
}
```

Check this [Demo](http://rextester.com/GECTW39697)

**NOTE:**

In order for your function to work, you need to add this code to your classes:

```
public object this[string propertyName] 
{
    get{
        Type myType = typeof(<YOUR CLASS HERE>);                   
        PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);
        return myPropInfo.GetValue(this, null);
    }
    set{
        Type myType = typeof(<YOUR CLASS HERE>);                   
        PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);
        myPropInfo.SetValue(this, value, null);
    }

}
```

**Bonus:** you can now retrieve values using `myObject["someproperty"]` and you can even set their values!